# iPad and iPhone not scrolling to anchored div

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I have tried to get both an iPad and iPhone to work with my current pen and it seems that I can't get it. I have tried to use  and SomeContent as well as the normal . The  will simply not scroll down to the div. I've tried to cut out the javascript, bootstrap, css, and even cut the page down to rudementary html for awhile but none of the tests seemed to fix it.

Included in the file are Bootstrap.js, Jquery.min.js, Bootstrap.min.css, and font-awesome.min.css

You can find the pen here: [Gregory Buhler Portfolio](http://codepen.io/Gregory-Buhler/pen/JXdMLg)

HTML:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand topnav" href="http://GregoryBuhler.com" target="_blank">Gregory Buhler</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-nav">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#home">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>


    <div id="home" class="text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="homecontent">
                        <h1>Gregory Buhler Website Design</h1>
                        <h3>Always on the fantastic side of life</h3>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End .homecontent -->
                </div>
                <!-- End .col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
            <!-- End .row -->
        </div>
        <!-- End .container -->
    </div>
    <!-- End #home -->

    <div id="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 text-background">
                    <h4>A Bit About Me</h4>
                    <p>When I was a kid my dad pushed for my brother and I to learn computers. I took to it like a fish to water. From 8 onwards my summers were spent indoors working away on simple scripting languages and later on some game modifications.</p>
                    <p>I won't lie, it wasn't easy getting past my <em>"it needs to be perfect all the time"</em> streak. In fact I still have that streak, I've just learned to fix and perfect as you go instead of making it perfect on the first go-round.</p>
                    <p>I absolutely love a challenge, critisism of my work used to cause me to clam up a bit. Over time I learned to take the constructive side of critisism and use it to better myself and the content I produce.</p>
                    <p>None of this would be possible without my amazing wife who puts up with my nose being buried in a book or in code for hours at a time every day. I want to provide the best life I can for her, and I'm good at tech and I love tech, this
                        is how I plan to provide for her the rest of our lives.</p>
                </div>
                <!-- End .com-sm-12 .col-md-4 .com-md-offset-2 .text-background -->
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 text-center">
                    <img class="img-circle vertical-align" src="http://i66.tinypic.com/2ywz3w5.jpg" alt="Gregory Buhler in his black cowboy hat.">
                </div>
                <!-- end .col-md-4 .col-md-offset-1 .text-center -->
            </div>
            <!-- End .row -->
        </div>
        <!-- End .container -->
    </div>
    <!-- End #about -->

    <div id="portfolio">
        <div class="portfoliocontent text-center">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Portfolio</h1>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                        <div class="imgholder">
                            <div class="img-rounded inset-shadow">
                                <img class="img-rounded" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=200×150&w=200&h=150">
                            </div>
                            <figcaption class="figure-caption">Placeholder</figcaption>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                        <div class="imgholder">
                            <div class="img-rounded inset-shadow">
                                <img class="img-rounded" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=200×150&w=200&h=150">
                            </div>
                            <figcaption class="figure-caption">Placeholder</figcaption>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                        <div class="imgholder">
                            <div class="img-rounded inset-shadow">
                                <img class="img-rounded" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=200×150&w=200&h=150">
                            </div>
                            <figcaption class="figure-caption">Placeholder</figcaption>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                        <div class="imgholder">
                            <div class="img-rounded inset-shadow">
                                <img class="img-rounded" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=200×150&w=200&h=150">
                            </div>
                            <figcaption class="figure-caption">Placeholder</figcaption>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                        <div class="imgholder">
                            <div class="img-rounded inset-shadow">
                                <img class="img-rounded" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=200×150&w=200&h=150">
                            </div>
                            <figcaption class="figure-caption">Placeholder</figcaption>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                        <div class="imgholder">
                            <div class="img-rounded inset-shadow">
                                <img class="img-rounded" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=200×150&w=200&h=150">
                            </div>
                            <figcaption class="figure-caption">Placeholder</figcaption>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                        <div class="imgholder">
                            <div class="img-rounded inset-shadow">
                                <img class="img-rounded" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=200×150&w=200&h=150">
                            </div>
                            <figcaption class="figure-caption">Placeholder</figcaption>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                        <div class="imgholder">
                            <div class="img-rounded inset-shadow">
                                <img class="img-rounded" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=200×150&w=200&h=150">
                            </div>
                            <figcaption class="figure-caption">Placeholder</figcaption>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="contactcontent text-center">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h1>Get ahold of me</h1>
                        <h3>Open Your Eyes to the Opportunities</h3>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="hor-big">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/GBProgramming" target="_blank" class="btn-inverse"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook
            </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/gregoryBuhler" target="_blank" class="btn-inverse"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter
            </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">
                        <a href="https://github.com/Gregory-Buhler" target="_blank" class="btn-inverse"><i class="fa fa-github"></i> Github
            </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">
                        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/gregorybuhler" target="_blank" class="btn-inverse"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i> Linkedin
            </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <div class="container text-center">
            <p>&#169; Website created by <a href="http://gregorybuhler.com">Gregory Buhler</a></p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#about {
    background: url(http://i63.tinypic.com/213ht14.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-top: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

#about .text-background {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    font-family: droid-serif;
    color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#about img {
    padding: 20px;
}

#about,
#contact,
#home,
#portfolio {
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 900px;
}

a.btn-inverse {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: auto;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    background-color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    border: rgb(60, 60, 60) 1px solid;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
}

a.btn-inverse:hover {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    text-decoration: none;
}

body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

#contact {
    background: url(http://i63.tinypic.com/2rp9tau.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

.contactcontent {
    padding-top: 25%;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
}

footer {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
    font-family: Cinzel;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
    color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
}

h2 {
    font-size: 3em;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: rgb(150, 150, 150)
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1.7em;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#home {
    background: url(http://i65.tinypic.com/vht1c2.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

.homecontent {
    padding-top: 25%;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
}

.hor-big {
    clear: both;
    border: 0;
    height: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px black;
}

.hor-big:after {
    content: "\00a0";
}

.imgholder {
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: rgb(20, 20, 20) 1px solid;
    background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
    width: 190px;
    height: 180px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.imgholder img {
    float: left;
}

.inset-shadow {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.inset-shadow:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

#my-row {
    display: table;
}

#my-row .content {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
}

.nav li:hover {
    background-color: rgb(28, 28, 28);
}

#portfolio {
    background: url(http://i67.tinypic.com/287nl8z.jpg) 50% 0 repeat fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

.portfoliocontent {
    padding-top: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
}

.portfoliocontent .row > div {
    transform: all .4s ease-in-out;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

JS:

```
$("nav ul li a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // animate the scroll
    y = $(this.hash).offset().top - 50;
    if ((y - window.pageYOffset) > 0) {
        time = y - window.pageYOffset;
    } else {
        time = window.pageYOffset - y;
    }

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: y
    }, time);
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!